# How can I play iptv url in react native expo application?

Tags: react-native, expo, m3u8, iptv

I'm trying to build a mobile application for live Tv using iptv and react native expo,but I don't know how can I play an m3u8 file,does any one have some idea how I can do that ?

Comment: Can you provide any m3u8 file link? So that I can play around it and tell you if anything useful I found.

Comment: you can try this one : https://live-hls-web-aja.getaj.net/AJA/index.m3u8